# Unwanted 48px margin over body?

Tags: html, css, margin

I was building a static html page for creating a wordpress theme.but now i notice that 48px margin is above the body element(I found it with chrome developer tools).i can fix it by just adding a -48px margin but what exactly is causing this problem,can someone help me.

#### My CSS

```
body{
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:1.72222;
    color:#34495e;
    font-family:Ubuntu;
    margin:0
}
aside {
    background: #31373d;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    font-weight: normal;
    color:#fff;
}
.main {
    margin-left: 20%;
}
.content{
    width: 65%;
    max-width: 760px;
    margin: 3rem auto;
}
```

Look at this live JSfiddle Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/aq96b/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `margin: 3rem auto;` from `.content`.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/aq96b/3/)

Comment: Thanks, i just removed 3rem and it was fixed

Comment: Using `padding` and you could `margin-left`.

Comment: Could also just double the `margin-left` on `.main` [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/aq96b/5/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 1):

It's the line

```
margin: 3rem auto;
```

in your .content that's causing this (if I properly understand the problem). Unchecking/removing that margin will move the content back up to the top left of your .main div.

To maintain a similar effect with the content position, you could add padding to the .main of the same amount ie

```
padding: 3em;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's coming from the div `.content`.  To correct this you should add `overflow:hidden` to `.main`

**Example**

```
.main {
    margin-left: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Alternatively you can set `.content` to `inline-block`.  This will also correct the issue.

**Example**

```
.content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```